# Pronunciation of eight, eighth, and eighty

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

What is the difference between the pronunciation of eight, eighth and eighty?

I played in Google translator, and is changing so little that I just can't figure out, what is happening...

I imagine if I talk with someone that really speak English in high speed, and I will probably will think it is just "8".

Is this hard for native-speakers too, or just for a Portuguese (Brazilian) speaker like me? Do you have some tip to learn something like that?

And if I go to different regions or English-countries, do I need to learn something more about 8, 80, and 8th?

Comment: They're all different. "8" has 1 syllable that ends with a sharp "t" sound. "8th" has 1 syllable ends with a "th" sound. "80" has 2 syllables, ending with an "ee" sound.

Comment: But this th pronounce is just like a sharp "t" isn't? And a sharp t is pronuntiated like: tee... but very fast... so... What i am missing...

Comment: No. The sharp "t" sound is short and can't really be held for a long time. The "th" sound can be held for as long as you keep pushing air through your front teeth.

Comment: Those three words are difficult to say distinctly.

Comment: I joined it.... Thanks! Can I ask this question in this other site? And maybe get some audio (wav or something like that) in answers?

Comment: @Lawrence  From the UK here and I actually don't say a sharp t on the end of eight, more sort of just like the word 'Ate' with a hard A and a trailing  fading 'te'

Comment: @WendyG Thanks for your comment. It varies with context for me, anywhere from something like a 'd' to almost a hiss, depending somewhat on the following word. "[S]harp t" describes the contrast with the "th" sound rather than where emphasis is placed. Perhaps I should have used the term [*plosive*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plosive).

Answer (score 6):

In India, we prounounce these as "ate, ate-th, A tea"

But another fact is that the pronunciation of " ate , ate-th and a tea" is probably different in every other country. So, now that you know that the pronunciation is near to "ate" and all, it won't create much of a confusion.You just have to figure out how people pronounce the basic words like ate and tea in a particular country.

Comment: Can you post the other pronounces in this cool way, for other countries from your view?

Comment: I don't think i have that kind of exposure.

Comment: But another fact is that the pronunciation of " ate , ate-th and a tea" is probably  different in every other country. So, now that you know that the pronunciation is near to "ate" and all, it won't create much of a confusion.You just have to figure out how people pronounce the basic words like ate and tea in a particular country.

Comment: Tks. If you include that on the answer i can mark your answer as the right answer!